# How to set bootclasspath when using the "internal" JavaCompiler

Tags: java, javacompiler

How can you resolve the following warning

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
```

when using the internal `JavaCompiler`?

Example code (slightly modified from my source):

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); 
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, null, null, compilerOptions, null, javaFileObjects);
task.call();
```

The obvious thing I tried was to supply `-bootclasspath` to `compilerOptions` in the example code above. But you can only supply options in the `Option.OptionGroup.BASIC` group (and it is not).

Edit:
Some more info: I am using OpenJdk11 and I get the warning for all sources up to 10.

Comment: I based that the option is not available on `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler().isSupportedOption(option)` maybe that is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the compiler, you can get a file manager to set the bootclasspath:

```
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
List<File> filePaths = ...;
fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.PLATFORM_CLASS_PATH, filePaths);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager.html#setLocation-javax.tools.JavaFileManager.Location-java.lang.Iterable-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardLocation.html#PLATFORM_CLASS_PATH